# Weather sealing door in apartment

Tags: doors, door-frame, weatherstripping

I've got two 1-3/8" thick doors that lead into a small room that contains the water heater/central heater for my apartment. This small room also has vents that open to the outside, so the room gets quite cold. The two doors both have 1 inch wide gaps between them and the floor.

What's the best way to seal this in a non-destructive fashion? I looked for slide-on door sweeps (something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0091SFM14)), but I couldn't find any that fit 1-3/8" doors with a 1 inch gap. I looked at stick-on door sweeps (like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072QDSJKT)) but I'm not sure how easy it will be to remove them. I'll also need some kind of easy-to-unstick foam for the sides and top of the door, I figure.

I also basically never open these doors, so I don't need a solution that's resilient to use.

Answer (score 1):

A draft stopper would probably work nicely, is not destructive, costs between $10 and $20, and stays in place even if you need to open the door:

[image: draft stopper]

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest solution to this problem, for a non-destructive method applicable to an apartment dweller, is to create a roll out of a bath towel and lay on the floor. Push it up against the bottom of the door to cut the draft that comes through under the door.

You really only need to do this during the coldest months of the year. If you happen to live in an area that gets extremely hot outside in the summer months and you use air conditioning inside the apartment you would want to place the towel roll by the door so hot air does not come in.